# How to assign function to other function in one file python script?

Tags: python, pytest

I can do this if I wrap them into python class:

```
class Foo:

    def generate_list(self):
        my_list = [3, 4, 5, 6]
        return my_list

    def get_first_list(self):
        lists = self.generate_list()
        first = lists[0]
        return first

class TestFoo:

    def fake_generate_list(self):
        return [10, 11]

    def test_get_first_list(self):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.generate_list = self.fake_generate_list # <----
        first = foo.get_first_list()
        assert first == 10 # PASSED (first is 10)
```

But it's failed, if I unwrap them without class:

```
def generate_list():
    print(generate_list)
    my_list = [3, 4, 5, 6]
    return my_list

def get_first_list():
    lists = generate_list()
    first = lists[0]
    return first

# Test

def fake_generate_list():
    return [10, 11]

def test_get_first_list():
    generate_list = fake_generate_list # <------
    first = get_first_list()
    assert first == 10 # FAILED (first still 3)
```

I know one alternative is using
`monkeypatch.setattr("myfilename.generate_list", fake_generate_list)`. But is
there any simple alternative just like `old_function =
fake_function`. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test_get_first_list`'s generate_list is a new local variable, not an assignment to the function `generate_list`, thus it's not visible inside `get_first_list`. You can write `global generate_list` at the top of `test_get_first_list`, then you're assigning to the function as you intended.

```
def test_get_first_list():
    global generate_list
    generate_list = fake_generate_list
    first = get_first_list()
    assert first == 10
```

This will rapidly lead you to writing bad / unmaintainable code though. See eg. [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)].

Comment: Yes, I ask this only for learning purposes, in production, I use classes or mock. +1 for the reason why it's failing.